# Using equality comparer in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Venue class, and a Coordinate class like so:

```
class Venue
{
    string Name;
    Coordinate coordinate;
}

class Coordinate
{
    double latitute;
    double longitude;
}
```

Now, I want to be able to select a venue based on a coordinate as follows:

```
List<Venue> venues = GetAllVenues();

var myVenue = venues.FirstOrDefault(venue=>venue.coordinate == myCoordinate);
```

I have an IEqualityComparer implementation, but the lambda expression does not have an overload which takes the IEqualityComparer as a parameter.

How do I use my equality comparer in a lambda expression?

EDIT:

My equality comparer looks like this:

```
class CoordinatesEqualityComparer:IEqualityComparer<Coordinate>
    {
        public bool Equals(Coordinate x, Coordinate y)
        {
            return x.RowIndex == y.RowIndex && x.ColumnIndex == y.ColumnIndex;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Coordinate obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

When I do a Union() operation, like so, it does not work correctly, even though coordinates in both lists are same.

```
List<Coordinates> coordinates; 
CoordinatesEqualityComparer comparer; 
coordinates.Union(someOtherListOfCoordinates, comparer);
```

However, when I do a union with itself, it works. What am I doing wrong? Does it have something to do with the GetHashCode() implementation?

Edit 2:
Fixing the GetHashCode() method seems to do the trick.

```
public int GetHashCode(Coordinates obj)
        {
            // Warning:Hack. Use two prime numbers to generate a hash based on two properties.
            return obj.RowIndex.GetHashCode() * 7 + obj.ColumnIndex.GetHashCode() * 13 ;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var ec = new YourEqualityComparer();
var myVenue = venues.FirstOrDefault(venue => 
                                         ec.Equals(venue.coordinate, myCoordinate));
```

---

Of course, another approach would be to define the `==` operator for your `Coordinate` class and then you wouldn't need an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class Coordinate
{
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) ||
               this == (other as Coordinate);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Coordinate l, Coordinate r)
    {
        return ((object)l == null && (object)r == null) || 
               ((object)l != null && (object)r != null) &&
               // equality check including epsilons, edge cases, etc.
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Coordinate l, Coordinate r)
    {
        return !(l == r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of `==` is broken. It calls itself on `l == null`, from there goes into infinite recursion which will either take forever (if some tail call optimization takes place) or overflow the call stack. Consider `(object)l == (object)null`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I was trying not to get mired in edge cases because that's beside the point of my example, but they found me anyway. Should be ok now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement `IEquatable<Coordinate>`, override Equals(object), override GetHashCode(), and == != operators like this:

```
public class Coordinate : IEquatable<Coordinate>
{
    public double Latitide { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Coordinate other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Latitide == other.Latitide && this.Longitude == other.Longitude;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Coordinate);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Latitide.GetHashCode() ^ this.Longitude.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Coordinate value1, Coordinate value2)
    {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(value1, null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(value2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value1, null) && !Object.ReferenceEquals(value2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value1, null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(value2, null))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return value1.Latitide == value2.Latitide && value1.Longitude == value2.Longitude;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Coordinate value1, Coordinate value2)
    {
        return !(value1 == value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a caution, you might get stack overflow within operator == etc due to it attempting to call itself with checking against null.  I normally use Object.ReferenceEquals(obj,null) to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  You are correct if you override the == and != operators you need to do the Object.ReferenceEquals.